# How to do an filter onChange in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the code below `filterNames()`

```
filterNames() {
    const { peoples } = this.state;
    this.setState({
      filtered: peoples.filter(item => item.name.includes(this.state.input)),
      currentPage:0
    });
    console.log(this.state.filtered)
}
```

That filters when I click this button

button:

```
<button className='search' onClick={this.filterNames}>
    Search
</button>
```

Input:

```
<input type="text" onChange={ this.getValueInput }></input>
```

I want it where when I type the letter 'a' on input, it filters.

Resuming: I want to filter without clicking the button, just when I type on input.

My code all:

```js
class Pagination extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
         
    const peoples = [
      {id:0, name:"Jean"}, 
      {id:1, name:"Jaquinha"}, 
      {id:2, name:"Ricardo"}, 
      {id:3, name:"JaCA"}, 
      {id:4, name:"Letiiicia"}, 
      {id:5, name:"Dai"}, 
      {id:6, name:"Da iIIane"}, 
      {id:7, name:"Tamy"}, 
      {id:8, name:"Tamyresss"},
      {id:9, name:"Tamyres"}, 
      {id:10, name:"Abeu"}, 
      {id:11, name:"Abellll"}
    ];
    
    this.state = {
      elementsPerPage:3,
      currentPage:0,
      peoples,
      input: "",
      filtered: peoples,
    };

    this.nextPage = this.nextPage.bind(this);
    this.previousPage = this.previousPage.bind(this);
    this.filterNames = this.filterNames.bind(this);
    this.getValueInput = this.getValueInput.bind(this);
  } 
  
  getValueInput (value) {
    this.setState({ input: value.target.value });
  }
    
  filterNames() {
    const { peoples } = this.state;
    this.setState({
      filtered: peoples.filter(item => item.name.includes(this.state.input)),
      currentPage:0
    });
    console.log(this.state.filtered)
  } 
  
  elementsOnScreen() {
    const { elementsPerPage, currentPage, filtered } = this.state;
    return filtered
      .map((item) => <li key={item.id}> {item.name} <button onClick={() => this.remove(item.name)}> Delete </button> </li>)
      .slice(currentPage*elementsPerPage, currentPage*elementsPerPage + elementsPerPage);
    
    if (this.state.filtered.length < 1) {
      this.setState({currentPage: this.state.currentPage - 1})
    }
  }

  remove = (id) => {
    console.log(this.state.filtered.length)
    if (this.state.filtered.length < 0) {
       this.setState({currentPange: this.state.currenPage - 1})
    }
    this.setState({filtered: this.state.filtered.filter(item => item.name !== id) })
  }
  
  nextPage() {
    console.log(this.state.filtered)

    const {elementsPerPage, currentPage, filtered} = this.state;
    
    if ((currentPage+1) * elementsPerPage < filtered.length){
      this.setState({ currentPage: this.state.currentPage + 1 });
    }
  }
  
  previousPage () {
    const { currentPage } = this.state;
    if(currentPage - 1 >= 0){
      this.setState({ currentPage: this.state.currentPage - 1 });
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="text" onChange={ this.getValueInput }></input>
        <button className='search' onClick={this.filterNames}> Search </button>
        <button onClick={this.previousPage}> Previous </button>
        <button onClick={this.nextPage}> Next </button>
        <h3>Current Page: {this.state.currentPage}</h3>
        <ul>Names: {this.elementsOnScreen()}</ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(
  <Pagination/>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: it sounds like you could do something like `onChange={() => {/* Call all handlers */}}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can update your **getValueInput** to handle the filtering.

```
getValueInput (evt) {
  const inputValue = evt.target.value;
  this.setState({ input: inputValue });
  this.filterNames(inputValue);
}

filterNames (inputValue) {
  const { peoples } = this.state;
  this.setState({
    filtered: peoples.filter(item => 
       item.name.includes(inputValue)),
    currentPage:0
  });
}
```

> **Note:** You have to pass in the **inputValue** because **React** batches the **setState** calls. If you check, your **this.state.input** will still be your previous value even after calling setState. Which is why you have to rely on the **evt.target.value** in **filterNames**

Dan gives a good brief explanation here about how React batches setState calls.
https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/10231#issuecomment-316644950

Comment: Thanks Man, i love you <3

But you would can explain me one thing?

That line `this.filterNames(inputValue)` in `getValueInput`. What it do exactly ?

Comment: Since you binded `this.getValueInput = this.getValueInput.bind(this);` in your constructor. `getValueInput` is binded to the class and has access to your component class functions through `this` and `this.filterNames` is one of the functions in your component. What happens is you're calling that class function and passing an argument so `filterNames` has access to it in the `parameter`.

Comment: If you need to learn more about functions I recommend you first read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions